# jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css not working in android webview after latest android upgrade (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, webview

I had designed a Web page using JQuery. I was able to load the page in Android Webview. The page was rendered correctly on the device (Nexus 5).

After the recent update of Android (to Marshmallow) for Nexus 5, I am not able to view the Web Page on the WebView. I just see a small circle in the center of the Webview.

The same works on devices running older Android.

While debugging I found out that after removing the line - " link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"", the page was getting displayed. But I need the css file to design the page in a correct way.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.
Need to add the following line (from [Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453806/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-execute-replacestate-on-history-cannot-be)) before the line - "

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
```