# jQuery ID & function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me. I have a problem!

e.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


    <body>
        <input type="button" id="clickmenow" value="ADD" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#clickmenow').click(function() {
    window.alert("DO IT");
});          
      </script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me why it is not work ?!
Also if i did:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("clickmenow").click(function(){
                window.alert("SHOWTHAT");
            });
        });
        </script>
```

It doesn't work! Any suggestions!

Comment: You forgot to import jQuery.

Comment: Jquery Lib is missing.

Comment: Just make sure to include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your `</body>` tag.

Comment: For the future, make sure you say what the problem is, not just that "it is not work" and asking "this code IS not working !! why ?!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from adding the mobile version of jQuery. Try adding this script before including jquery mobile.

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="clickmenow" value="ADD" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#clickmenow').click(function() {
                window.alert("DO IT");
            });          
      </script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i add this is not work :(

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Do you have the css file?

Comment: i'm using sublime text , and browser safari , there is no error but the button doesn't work

Comment: yes there is file has .css

Comment: It runs fine here. I`m not sure I understand exactly your problem. The button is showing, but when you click it, nothing happens?

Comment: when i do [code] <input type="button" onclick="somefunction()" /> it work ! but if with id < input type="button" id="anything" />
and i do the hash $("anything").click( function() {//code here });it doesn't work !

Comment: yes nothing happen !,,i'm using mac os x , i don't know where is the problem ! ! !

Comment: did you test the code on my answer? nothing happened when you clicked the button?

Comment: yes , now it's work ! but why ? how ?

Comment: I was getting a security error due to jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js, which you were not using. I removed that and some unnecessary code and added a up-to-date version of jQuery

Comment: For more info on that error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453806/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-execute-replacestate-on-history-cannot-be

Comment: thank you , you are man ! really <3

Comment: updated the answer with a script that allows you to use the mobile version as well =)

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as correct =)

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have enough reputation to comment on a post. But a good way to debug in safari is to go into preferences and then in the advanced section of preferences at the very bottom there is a checkbox that says, "Show develop menu in menu bar." Make sure this box is checked.

After that you go to the Develop section of your menu bar and select the option show error console. This will show you the error you are experiencing.

Here is a picture of what the error console looks like and an example of errors. The errors are displayed in red text.

[The Error Console in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG5St.png)

As to the problem with your code it is in fact that you didn't include a link to a jQuery library. You can do this a few ways. The way that was suggested earlier will only work when you have an internet connection. If you want you can download the jQuery library from their website and save it to your websites folder. Then all you need to do is just link to the file like you would any other external javascript file by using the script tags.

jQuery download page:
https://jquery.com/download/

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/blur.js"></script>
```